# OWASP ZAP Application Security testing for a network of application servers

Tags: owasp, zap

I am about to use ZAP to assess vulnerability of my Web Application. My architecture is such that internally the "application server" under test, calls APIs from other Web Application Servers. I am cloning a single application server to carry out my vulnerability test. Am I supposed to isolate the other servers as well, while they are not under test? Will ZAP trigger something that will affect other Application Servers?
I am not so well-versed with each and every test that ZAP performs on the "application server" hence the question..

Answer (score 0):

Thats very difficult to say without knowing more about your architecture.

If you scan www.example.com with either of the ZAP spiders then ZAP will attempt to explore all of the functionality available. If ZAP finds links to www.example1.com then it will ignore those as they are out of scope (unless you tell ZAP otherwise). However if some features call APIs from www.example2.com 'behind the scenes' then those APIs will probably be invoked as a side affect of ZAP scanning www.example.com.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Thank You for the answer Psiinon, so my url under test is something like https://example.com.something.dosomething which internally calls https://anotherapp.com.something.dosomething. I was planning to not clone the anotherapp.com server as it was not under test. But as you mentioned there is a probability, I might  then have to clone the entire group of application servers to start my tests.. This will add to my cost :(

Comment: I think thats a good plan. ZAP has no knowledge of the internals of https://example.com.something.dosomething/ and so could easily do something that ends up calling https://anotherapp.com.something.dosomething/ You can exclude parts of your application from the ZAP scan, but I dont know how easy that will be for you.